# Is it possible to get a file name while dragging it on a UWP app?

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, win-universal-app

I need to allow or disallow file dropping on my UWP app by checking which kind of file is being dragged by user.
Is it possible to get a file name while dragging it?

Comment: Isn't easier to [try](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dragstartingeventargs.data.aspx) and see?

Comment: Use e.DataView.GetStorageItemsAsync() in your DragEnter event handler.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You just need to implement DragEnter event handler then use the following code.

```
    private async void DropArea_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        IReadOnlyList<IStorageItem> files = await e.DataView.GetStorageItemsAsync();
        StorageFile file = files.First() as StorageFile;

        var name = file.Name;
    }
```

Comment: I got an exception: '-$exception {"Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."} System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'

Comment: I think maybe you updated UI in async method